# Striping & Removing numbers in a Set

Tags: python, parsing, strip

I have a simple set that contains strings and some of those strings are numbers. (i.e. `'1'`, `'45'`, `'5'`, `'39'`).

Some of the strings have dashes (`-`) or plus (`+`) signs in them. (i.e. `'55+'`, `'1-3'`).

I have created a function that should parse the `set` and remove the digits along with removing the characters and remove any words that are capitalized.

**Function:**

```
def parse_set(s):
    for word in s.copy():
        word.strip('+-')
        if word.istitle() or word.isdigit():
            s.remove(word)

    completed_set = set(filter(None, s))

    return completed_set
```

But when I pass in a set, any regular number *without* any `-` or `+` are removed. But numbers that *do* contain the characters still remain.

I had thought that the `.strip()` method would take care of that?

Comment: `word =  word.strip('+-')`

Comment: `strip` doesn't work in-place!

Comment: @Rawing got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Rawing noted in his comment, `strip` doesn't work in place, and strings are immutable, so you have to assign back the result to `word` again:

```
word = word.strip('+-') # Rawing
```